# Ubuntu graphics / boot problem after RAM upgrade

Tags: boot, 22.04, intel-graphics, ram

I have an old PC that worked fine since maybe 2012 (motherboard+processor 2014). Recently I got Ubuntu 22.04 and everything was working fine. Even after my 12-year-old VGA died, the onboard video kept all going, but the memory was a little outdated.

The problem came after I got a stick of 8GB 1600hz Kingston RAM. The BIOS detected the new stick without doing any config, but after boot Ubuntu freezes on the login screen.

[image: green freezing screen]

I tried every memory slot, 8GB alone, 12GB combined with every slot possible, but I still had the same problem. The BIOS is OK but Ubuntu is freezing. When using both sticks, 12GB both at 1333MHz. When using only new stick, 8GB 1600MHz without any problem.

I managed to boot into a `nomodeset` and recovery mode (grub setting) and Ubuntu got past the login screen just as usual back when only 4GB was used. All the 12GB RAM was working, but the graphics was terrible, the display got "unknown display" instead of LG Electronics 23" and the only resolution possible was 800x600.

I tried to boot on Live Ubuntu USB stick and got the same green freeze problem.

- I ran Memtest86+ and both sticks passed.
- I created a swap file with 13GB, originally my installation has a swap partition with 8GB.

What should I do? I really don't want to install Windows anymore, could be Os problem or something on BIOS, drivers?

- Intel Core i5 3470 Ivy bridge (Intel HD graphics 2500)
- Gigabyte b75m-d3h rev 1.0
- 4GB RAM  1333hz Patriot DDR3
- Newly added 8GB 1600MHz HyperX DDR3
- Sapphire HD 6950 2GB (dead)
- Power supply SevenTeam 550w-ag
- monitor LG M23 7WA